# How can I output a report in PDF format, where the name consists of values from fields?

Tags: vba, ms-access, report, save-as

I want to add functionality to my Access 2007 report whereby a PDF copy of the report is created at the click of a button. I know that there is an `OutputTo` macro which can do this for me, but it does not allow me to include report field values as part of the PDF's filename, namely:

```
[Client Organisations].Code + "-" + Clients.Code + "-" + Invoices_Code + "-" + Format([Invoice Date],"yyyy") + ".pdf"
```

While I have seen this [MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/bf5dc54a-9c39-42e7-a175-2984825a60be) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968798/access-vba-save-report-as-pdf-binary), I don't see the use of field values in any of the answers.

I reckon VBA code is the way to go, so I (unsuccessfully) tried the following:

```
Private Sub Create_PDF_Click()
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, "" + [Client Organisations].Code  
+ "-" + Clients.Code + "-" + Invoices_Code + "-" + Format([Invoice Date],"yyyy")
+ ".pdf", True
End Sub
```

> Run-time error '2465':
>
> Microsoft Office Access can't find the field '|' referred to in your expression

Any ideas out there?

Comment: this 'can't find the field' error usually appears when something is wong somewhere in the libraries: version issue, unrecognised parameter, etc. I guess @jonH is right: you are missing something outside VBA to have your PDF reports printed.

Comment: @Philippe: The macro works fine, the issue is with getting VBA to recognize the fields.

Comment: in this case try a few 'debug.print' in the immediate window and test each one of the parameters of your file name to find which one is faulty:

? debug.print [Client Organisations].Code
? debug.print Clients.Code
etc

Comment: @Philippe: issue resolved (see my post below). Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got it to work (eventually).

The following `sub` did the trick:

```
Private Sub Create_PDF_Click()

Dim myPath As String
Dim strReportName As String

DoCmd.OpenReport "Invoices", acViewPreview

myPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\"
strReportName = Report_Invoices.[Client Organisations_Code] + "-" +
Report_Invoices.Clients_Code + "-" + Report_Invoices.Invoices_Code + "-" +
Format(Report_Invoices.[Invoice Date], "yyyy") + ".pdf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, myPath + strReportName, True
DoCmd.Close acReport, "Invoices"

End Sub
```

Two caveats:

1. The report needs to be opened before printing.
2. Refer to fields by the same name that the report sees it as. That `[Client Organisations].Code` was `[Client Organisations_Code]` in the report.

Comment: Is [Client Organisations] as subform control? If so, the usual syntax to refer to a control or field in the form embedded in the subform control is Me![Client Organisations].Form!Code. It would have been much easier to offer you an answer if you'd specified that [Client Organisations] was a subform. If it's not, then I don't understand why your solution works.

Comment: @David : It's not. `[Client Organisations].Code` was a field that the report saw as `[Client Organisations_Code]` because of the `SELECT` query that the report is based on: `SELECT [Client Organisations].Code AS [Client Organisations_Code]...`.

Comment: You should avoid that kind of thing in your recordsources. I would say. That is, having the same field name from multiple tables is an error in the SQL statement, either because it's redundant (it's a PK/FK relating two tables) or because it's a design error (fields that don't store the same data should not be given the same name in multiple tables). Also, putting spaces in table/field names is inadvisable. Camel case without spaces is just as readable and quite a bit easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Its easier to Dim a string and put your entire expression there and then debug it to see if it contains the valid report name.

Like this:

```
Dim strReportName as String

strReportName = [Client Organisations].Code   
+ "-" + Clients.Code + "-" + Invoices_Code + "-" + Format([Invoice Date],"yyyy") 
+ ".pdf"

//then try to print strReportName before you use DoCmd.OutputTo.
```

Comment: @JonH: I made the relevant changes, clicking on the button does nothing. No errors, nothing.

Comment: You did debug what strReportName displays?  Also don't you need a pdf distiller / printer to print to PDF.  You cannot expect DoCmd.OutputTo to really create a pdf without a writer do you ?

Comment: There's a downloadable add-in to do PDF generation in Office 2007. It is required for the acFormatPDF parameter to work. That is, Access 2007 without that add-in installed will not be able to output to PDF via the DoCmd.OutputTo command.

Comment: @David: I already have the add-in installed. @JonH: Now it can't find the field `[Client Organisations].Code`. `Me.[Client Organisations].Code` doesn't work either. Run-time error '2465'