# Exporting Office 2007 documents to PDF without using Microsoft's add-in?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, ms-office

I have an automatically generated report which displays a number of fields from a single record of a query. The end goal is actually to automate the exportation of this report to a PDF file, so that other users can automatically generate PDF files from an Access 2007 form.

There is a [common solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296884/how-can-i-output-a-report-in-pdf-format-where-the-name-consists-of-values-from) that use `DoCmd.OutputTo` and `acFormatPDF`, but this requires the user to have the add-in which allows saving to PDFs in Office 2007 applications. By default, my end user will not have this add-in installed and I do not think I can rely on them ever having it installed.

Is there another way to get to a PDF, which doesn't involve additional add-ins or applications?

Comment: Why do you need an add-in? PDF support is baked in to Office 2007

Comment: @AlexK. - No, it isn't. http://new.office-watch.com/2010/saving-to-pdf-in-access-2007/

Comment: If no add-ins or other installs are allowed then you can't do this with Office 2007

Comment: "Save to PDF" capability was included with Office 2007 Service Pack 1.  Are your users actually running Office 2007 applications without having installed the official service packs?

Comment: @HansUp Yeah... Local machines have the service pack, but all remote desktop users do not have it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the ExportAsFixedFormat method? e.g. `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF FileName:=“sales.pdf” Quality:=xlQualityStandard DisplayFileAfterPublish:=True` 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238907%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: That link is for Excel, and states that it will not work without the add-in.