# Access 2010 Print to .pdf with variable filename

Tags: ms-access, macros, export-to-pdf

I'd like to print to .pdf out all records of a query, using a report. I have more than 1k records, and would like to save each record as a .pdf. I have concatenated the field "filename" within the query, with the intent to save the report using the "filename" field. The end result would be to click a button "print?" and the database would print to .pdf each record and save the file based on the "filename" field.

I know very little about VBA, and am working through a macro.
[Macro for Printing Training Checklist report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhD2C.jpg)

So, I'm printing a [Report].
The report name is "R Training Checklist".
The variable filename is "filename"

The end result would be a .pdf file saved with the data entered into field "filename" at the identified location.

If I use Output File 
"C:\Users\mabanes\Creative Cloud Files\Training Checklists\test2.pdf"
...I have no problems.  But, I don't want 1k records names "test2.pdf" where I have to go and individual rename each record.

It seems I have something wrong in the expression, but can't seem to figure it out. 
"C:\Users\mabanes\Creative Cloud Files\Training Checklists\" & Reports![R Training Checklist].[Filename] & ".pdf"

Comment: Is the exclamation mark necessary in your expression? I noticed it has `[Reports!].[R Training Checklist]`

Comment: no idea...was one of many combinations I tried.

Comment: See: [Ouput Report to PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296884/how-can-i-output-a-report-in-pdf-format-where-the-name-consists-of-values-from)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Create_PDF_Report()

Dim myPath As String
Dim strReportName As String

DoCmd.OpenQuery "QUERYNAME", acViewPreview

myPath = "C:\Users\mabanes\Creative Cloud Files\Training Checklists\"
strReportName = Report_Name.[Whatever you want here] + "etc." + ".pdf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, myPath + strReportName, True
DoCmd.Close acReport, "Reports"

End Sub
```

Should work for you with a bit of configuring to match your desired filename/path.

Comment: So, I get a Compile Error.

    Private Sub Command29_Click()

    Dim myPath As String
    Dim strReportName As String

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Q Tasks Assigned", acViewPreview

    myPath = "C:\Users\mabanes\Creative Cloud Files\Training Checklists\"
    strReportName = Report_R Training Checklist.[Filename] + ".pdf"

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, myPath + strReportName, True
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "Reports"

End Sub

Comment: sorry that looks funky...
the like giving me problems is the strReportName = line...